# Java Character with value greater than 127 sending via tcp

Tags: java, arrays, char

Good day,

I am having some trouble. I am trying to send a character array over the network to a server.

here is my code:

```
char[] arr= {3,4};    
public void sendMessage(String message){
    if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
        out.print(arr);
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

When I run that, lanshark detects that it recieved a packet with 2 bytes of data. ok good all is well.

Now when i run this:

```
 char[] arr= {3,160};      // notice 160 *****
public void sendMessage(String message){
    if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
        out.print(arr);
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

lanshark says that the packet has 3 bytes of data? the exact data is :

> 03 c2 a0

Now why is it adding the c2 in there? i understand that it has some thing to do with the fact that my char is bigger than 127. But i need to send this value of 160 .

Please can you help me. Do i need to use another type of data, or send it in a different way? I know you can do this in C. How can i do it in java?

here is the code for my out object:

```
PrintWriter out;
out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
```

Thanks

Comment: what happens when u use byte[] instead of char[]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, the program is doing exactly what you told it to do.  It is sending two characters; i.e. the unicode codepoints `3` (`\u0003`) and `160` (`\u00a0`).  These characters are being encoded using your platform's default character encoding ... which appears to be UTF-8.  The bytes `c2 a0` are the UTF-8 encoding for the `\u00a0` character.

But what you are actually trying to do is send 2 bytes.

In Java `char` is a 16 bit type, not an 8 bit type.  If you want to send 8 bit values you need to use the `byte` type.

The other mistake you are making is that you are trying to send (essentially) binary data using a `Writer`.  The `Writer` interface is for (16-bit) character oriented data.  You should be using the `OutputStream` API ...

Anyhow ... here's a code snippet to illustrate how you should send an array of bytes;

```
byte[] arr = new byte[]{3, (byte) 160);
OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
out.write(arr);
```

---

> I just changed it to that now, " out.print(new String(arr).getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))); " and this is the data i get on wireshark: 11 bytes : 5b42403431653230396538 it should still be 2 bytes?

You are making it worse!

Lets take this apart:

- `new String(arr)` gives you a 2 character String.
- `.getBytes(...)` will turn that into a 3 byte array containing the bytes `03 c2 a0`.
- `out.print(...)` will attempt to call a `print` method on the `PrintWriter` API.

But which one?  Well you supplied an argument whose declared type is `byte[]`.  And that will result in you calling `print(Object)`.

But wait a minute ... what does `PrintWriter.print(Object)` do?  Well the first thing is that it does is to call `toString()` on the argument.

And what does that do?  Well since the object is a `byte[]`, this calls the default `toString()` method provided by `java.lang.Object`.  And that gives you a String that looks like `B[@xxxxxxxx` where `[B` is the "class name" for a byte array, and the sequence of `x`s is a hexadecimal representation of the array object's identity hashcode!

And then you output that *that* String.

And behold your 2 bytes (actually characters) have turned into 11 bytes.

Comment: Thanks:byte[] arr = new byte[]{3, (byte) 160);
OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
out.write(arr);

Comment: Ok so now i have got the sending working correctly, I just want to check that i am on the right track before i start with the receiving. Currently, My input consists of a 'BufferedReader in;' and a 'in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); '   What do i need to change on this?  Do i need to use an inStream instead?

Comment: Just wrap the socket input stream in a BufferedInputStream, and use one of the `read` methods.

Comment: Like this:            `in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream())));` ?

Comment: No.  Like this `InputStream in = BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream())`.   It is really simple.  If you are sending / receiving bytes, DON'T turn them into characters.  If you are sending / receiving characters, DON'T represent them as arrays of bytes.

Comment: Ok i now have, 'in = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());'   but no win my while loop i had 'String message = in.readLine();'  this no longer works, so i now have to use 'in.read(buffer)'  but what i am not sure abotu is it returns and integer and not a string or and array of bytes?

Comment: Have you read the javadoc for the method?  It explains what the method returns.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't told us anything about `out` - not even the type - but I strongly suspect it's using UTF-8 to encode your character data. U+00A0 (i.e. character 160) is encoded as 0xc2 0xa0 in UTF-8.

Using UTF-8 is almost certainly the *best* thing to do if you control both the reading and writing code: it means the whole of Unicode is available to you. If you used ISO-8859-1 (which is what I suspect you expected to use - a single byte per character, for all characters) you would be limiting yourself to only the range [U+0000, U+00FF].

Answer (score 0):

You can make it as follow to send your data as "UTF-8":

```
out.print(new String(arr).getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Also you have to create your output stream with UTF-8 encoding as follow:

```
out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8")), true);
```

Now you will send your `char` array encoded with UTF-8, so up to 8 bytes per char (max value of 256). See answer of @JonSkeet to understand why you need "UTF-8" encoding.

Comment: I just changed it to that now, "   out.print(new String(arr).getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));  "   and this is the data i get on wireshark:  11 bytes  : 5b42403431653230396538     it should still be 2 bytes?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the in and out are in the same encoding,then you will get exactly what you want. eg.,

**When out sending**:

```
 mPrintWriterClient = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new    OutputStreamWriter(mSocket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8")), true);
```

**when in receiving**:

```
 mBufferedReaderClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mSocket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
```